# Работа с Excel средствами C#

Tags: c#, excel

В Excel есть плагин "Поиск решений". Подскажите пожалуйста можно ли программно использовать его. Если да, то как ?

Answer (score 0):

В C# есть отдельная [библиотека Solver Foundation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/devlabs/hh145003.aspx)

[Статья.](https://habrahabr.ru/company/microsoft/blog/118593/)

Comment: Спасибо , буду смотреть